# Magmi csv format?

Tags: magento, magmi

I can 't seem to find an example of the format `Magmi` wants for the csv data. Could someone please provide a one-line example of a successful product import?

Edit:
Magmi Wiki: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

actually, it will depends on many factors (if you're importing images, creating categories, relationing configurable products, etc...), so there isn't a *correct* answer to your question.
But you can export a csv file of all magento's sample products (system -> Import/Export -> Dataflow - Profiles -> Export All Products) and take that as a reference, Magmi will understand it.
Notice that in order to use some parameters (for example the visibility values "Not Visible Individually", "Catalog and Search", etc...) as strings you'll have to use Magmi's "Generic Mapper" plugin.
I have spent the last month using it intensively, and must say I love it. If you have a more specific question don't hesitate to ask, it's still fresh in my brains :)
HTH

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that Magmi often has it's own column names and requirements for field values. So, if you have a standard Magento import CSV, certain columns and fields will not get parsed.

for example, on a typical import magento uses "config_attributes" & "associated" as column names.  For Magmi, you must use "configurable_attributes" and "simples_skus" respectively

As for the field requirements, the fields must often be in integer format. [Magmi provides a "Generic mapper v0.0.6a"](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Generic_mapper) plugin that takes care of most of the standard mappings. For example, rather than using strings to assign "visiblity", magmi requies this value to be integer. The Generic mapper uses a configuration file that takes care of this:

visibility.csv
"Not Visible Individually",1
"Catalog",2
"Search",3
"Catalog, Search",4

Answer (score 3):

Magmi is a wonderful addon - and really powerful with the plugins.

For information on it I'd recommend using the wiki at http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page.

For the csv, look at http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Import_-_CSV_datasource.

But as OSdave said, it is really powerful, and doesn't work with one csv format since you can remap and manipulate the fields anyway.

Hope that helps a little.