# How to add large amout of product in magento1.7

Tags: magento, addition, categories, product

I've just started working on magento 1.7 recently , and i know how to add categories and product one by one ,but i've large amount of categories and product.Is there any alternative to add large amount of categories in one way? 
I've heard about of sample data , is it a solution of my above problem , if it is than how to use that?

Please help me in this matter.

Comment: I m waiting for any help.
please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed this - look into MAGMI for mass importing large amounts of product data into Magento;

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=What_is_magmi

Here's a link to the section on categories;

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_categories

Comment: thanx for valuable help.
But , I am using magento1.7 and magmi 0.7.12 , which is useful for magento upto version 1.6. And is there any magmi version for magento1.7?

Comment: Yes - check the link, Magmi has been updated to support CE 1.7 :)

Comment: I m trying to make csv file for category import.
but , i don't know how should i give name to each column in csv file?
How this column get match in database tables?

Comment: And also , what should be the sequence of column in csv with respect to magento categories???

Comment: Here's a good thread on that http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7463880/magmi-csv-format